# Dropbox: can't restore deleted files

Tags: dropbox

I'm using Dropbox on two linux machines, one with fedora and the other with ubuntu.

I deleted all the files of dropbox on fedora machine a long time ago. And then I havn't used that machine since.

Today, I opened the fedora machine and ubuntu machine both. Then I notice about 6000  dropbox files were deleted on my ubuntu machine. I tried to restore the files on events details. But there is no option of `Restore these files` (https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/400)

what can I do?

Comment: I think like said there is certain time limit for files by default have a look at this https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/969

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox only keeps history for 30 days by default. The exception to this is if you have either Dropbox for Business or if you have Extended Version History in Dropbox Pro. The latter allows you to restore to a previous version of anything changed within the last 12 months, or if you were a member before November 2014 then you can restore to any point in time, just like Dropbox for Business.

As you have deleted from Fedora within the Dropbox directory, Dropbox has synced the cloud version of your files to the deleted state, and now when you've booted Ubuntu and the Dropbox daemon has ran, it has now synced that machine to the deleted state.

I see there are two options for you:

- You could try a restore from the filesystem using a tool such as [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/). You can try this on both your Ubuntu and Fedora systems as they both carried the files.
- You could [contact Dropbox support](https://www.dropbox.com/support) and see if there is any chance of them restoring the data. It may be hanging around on their systems somewhere waiting to be purged, so there is a small chance they could recover it. Don't hold your breath though. See their guide [My files are missing. How do I get them back?](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/969).